# Why the function argument returns undefined when using props?

Tags: javascript, react-native, state, setstate, react-props

I am building an app using `react-native`. I have 3 components namely `Ind.js`, `Buttons.js`, `Rain.js`. I am required to select an option in `Rain` and save it in the state of `Ind` for further processing. Since  `Rain` component is not directly related to `Ind` but is connected via a `navigation route` in `Buttons`.
I am using `react-navigation`.

To do so I created a function `onSelect()` in `Ind` which does the `setState` and passed it to `Buttons` via props and passed again to `Rain` then I executed the function, the problem is the function is getting called but no parameters are passed ie, it `console.logs` `null` then `undefined`.

I have tried to `console.log` the parameters that are passed to `Ind`.

`Ind.js`

```
export default class Ind extends Component {
constructor(){
super();
this.state = { report: null}
}
onSelect = (newreport) => {
      this.setState({
        report: newreport
      })
      console.log("Parameter: ", newreport)
      console.log("State: ", this.state.report)
    }

render(){
return(
<Buttons selectReport={() => this.onSelect()}
)

}

}
```

`Buttons.js`

```
export default class Buttons extends Component{
constructor(props){
super(props);
}
render(){
return(
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate('Rain',{
                  selectReport: this.props.selectReport });
                }}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Rain</Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>
)
}
}
```

`Rain.js`

```
export default class Rain extends Component{
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = {
selection: "Test"
}
this.selectOption = this.selectOption.bind(this);
}
selectOption = () => {
this.props.navigation.state.params.selectReport(this.state.selection)
}
}
```

The `console log` return first `Parameter: undefined State: null` which is understandable because nothing is clicked but after clicking it shows
`Parameter: undefined State: undefined`.
What is happening? I am a beginner and is there something wrong in binding or sending the props?
Please Explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with arrow function, you need to call like,

```
<Buttons selectReport={() => this.onSelect} > //without parenthesis
```

also `setState` is `async` so you need to use `callback` in `setState` to print value.

You need to do this,

```
export default class Ind extends Component {
  constructor(){
   super();
   this.state = { report: null}
  }
  onSelect = (newreport) => {
      console.log("Parameter: ", newreport)
      this.setState({
        report: newreport
      },()=> console.log("State: ", this.state.report)) //prints in callback
  }

  render(){
   return(
    <Buttons selectReport={() => this.onSelect}>
   )
  }
}
```

Comment: When I use `<Buttons selectReport={this.onSelect}` it gives this.props.navigation.state.params.selectreport is not a function but If I use `<Buttons selectReport={() => this.onSelect}` it works. Why?

Comment: `<Buttons selectReport={() => this.onSelect}` bind `this` automatically.

Comment: Why it so confusing .... I am having difficulties with `binding`. can you direct to some resources?

Comment: and also what about the parameters ? that was mentioned in another answer?

Comment: That parameter was static in another answer. When you pass a function to child component and expect a param from child then you don't need parenthesis and from child you can pass param.

Comment: Refer this when to use arrow function and how- https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html

Comment: What about the parameters that are needed as stated by another answer?

Comment: That parameter is just a static value, when you pass value from child to parent it won't replace that value and you will get wrong value in parent.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't put any `parameters` in the **click button**. However, the function is receiving `parameters` as values. Of course it points to `undefind`.

```js
onSelect = (newreport) => {
      this.setState({
        report: newreport
      })
      console.log("Parameter: ", newreport)
      console.log("State: ", this.state.report)
    return this.state.report;
    }

render(){
return(
<Buttons selectReport={this.onSelect("value")}
)
```

Comment: When I do this ... and click the `Touchable opacity` button it says `this.props.navigation.state.params.selectreport` is not a function ?

Comment: @random_user There is no result value in your function. Please enter the result as my answer.

Comment: I did what your answer stated.. still the above error

Answer (score 0):

setState is async function so that's why after the first click you get null (because it didn't change yet) however somewhere in your code passing value of newreport is wrong.

Comment: yes, that's right, but the second time it should print the desired values right?

Comment: yup but obviously somewhere passing not working, can you put console.log on every component and check in which moment is broken ?

Comment: I should console log in `Buttons` right? because that's the middle? How should I do it though? In `Ind` I logged it, undefined and in `Rain` I logged the state and the function reference also..all are working fine.